# CORS issue in Angular js $http.get even after enabling Allow cross origin header

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have enabled the Allow cross origin header for my APIs and it is working fine. http://mydomain/api/apiName.

But when I try to GET a text file which is in the same domain I am getting the CORS issue. 
http://mydomain/folderName/fileName

I tried to use JSONP but getting Unexpected token < error.

I have to read the content of the text file (which has html content) and bind it in angular rich text editor.

Please help.

Thanks in Advance.!

Comment: so, just to make things a bit clear your angular app is on a different domain from your api and text file?

Comment: Ya.. I am trying to access my api and text file from localhost.